# Gwt + adfs combination

Tags: gwt, servlets, adfs2.0

I am new to adfs and what I want to do is in my gwt project provide afds login on click of a login.
Basically on click of login button in my gwt app it should get the user from the current adfs session if established or get it from adfs directly.

How should I go about this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by using the concept of fedlet + adfs.